# O que fazer com a tag [plotly]?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags, tag-específica, wikis-de-tags

No momento a tag [plotly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plotly) é usada exclusivamente para se referir ao [plotly.js](https://plotly.com/javascript/), mas *plotly* tem adaptações para Python, R, Julia, F# e MATLAB. São adaptações dos mesmos "desenvolvedores" (ou empresa).

A recomendação de uso (fragmento) atual é:

> Plotly.js é uma biblioteca open source, de alto nível para declaração de gráficos construída com base em d3.js e stack.gl. Ela vem com mais de 20 tipos de gráficos, incluindo gráficos 3D, estatísticos e mapas SVG.

Em resumo, atualmente a tag é usada para qualquer uma das linguagens citadas, mas a descrição dá a entender que se refere somente a JavaScript, então tenho duas sugestões:

### Sugestão #1

Manter a tag "plotly", mas melhorar a descrição, servindo para qualquer linguagem que exista uma adaptação dessa biblioteca, descrevendo o mínimo ainda sim esclarecendo o suficiente, algo como:

> Plotly são bibliotecas para criar gráficos e mapas com suporte para Python, R, Julia, F#, MATLAB e JavaScript. Mais detalhes em https://plotly.com/graphing-libraries/

### Sugestão #2

Ou dividir em tags por linguagem, seguindo como descrito no próprio site https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/ a tag para quando for a biblioteca de Python ficaria `plotly.py`, já que é uma maneira como se referem

Para JavaScript como é referido no site https://plotly.com/javascript/getting-started/#plotlyjs-cdn ficaria `plotly.js`

Para pacote de [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) parece que não usam outro termo a não ser `plotly`, ainda sim para facilitar no site creio que o melhor seja `plotly-r` ou `r-plotly`.

Espero a opinião da comunidade e de usuários de R e plotly sobre tudo isso, pois não sei se facilitará.

Comment: plotly-js (ou plotly-javascript) e plotly-python acredito que seja a grafia mais próxima das outras tags (creio que o js não faz parte do nome)

Comment: @Bacco até concordo, mas tem tags que seguem o .js ou .py justamente pela forma como são usadas por essas comunidades e esse parece ser um caso, no entanto se não atrapalhar, também creio que seria mais adequada.

Comment: As tags "js" estão meio bagunçadas nesse sentido, tem algumas que são "algojs", outras são "algo-js" ou "algo.js" (e algumas tem sinônimos pras versões com/sem hífen ou ponto, outras não). Mas enfim, acho que a sugestão 1 é uma opção válida, ficaria similar ao que temos hoje com a tag [tag:selenium] (mas digo isso sem conhecer a fundo o plotly)

Comment: Penso que o ponto é só se fizer parte do "nome própro" da coisa, tipo `three.js`, o que não parece ser o caso aqui, o nome da lib independente da linguagem me parece ser `plotly`. Se é "qualificador" do nome, o nosso separador oficial é o `-`. Claro que  vale uma análise melhor antes de aplicar.

Comment: Como o usuário vai começar digitando o nome da lib, eu usaria plotly-X e não X-plotly. O que acham de já usar plotly-r plotly-javascript (ou js) e plotly-python só para ir organizando, e se precisar renomear renomeamos depois? Uma vez separado fica fácil trocar o nome de chegarmos em outro consenso. cc Guilherme @hkotsubo - O importante é a descrição de uso estar clara

Comment: @Bacco Acho que podemos seguir sua ideia (separar plotly-x, plotly-y etc). Realmente fica mais fácil juntar depois, se for o caso.

Comment: Não gosto da ideia de tags muito abrangentes, mas não gosto de tags muito específicas a ponto de ter 2 ou 3 questões no total. Essa tag tem 20 questões, e aparecem questões uma vez na vida e outra na morte. Eu sugiro renomear `plotly.js` para `plotly` e criar um aliás do vice-versa disso para sugerir a correção, além de remover a menção à linguagem/motor que ela usa na descrição e usar o que a própria documentação oficial já diz.

Comment: @CypherPotato felizmente não existe a tag `plotly.js`, então fica como está, que é a minha primeira sugestão, melhorar o campo *Recomendação de uso (fragmento)*. Vou aguardar até sábado, acaso alguém apresente algum ponto de vista, acaso não, vou considerar a publicação como resolvida e melhorar o *fragmento*